# Send GSM/AT commands to an iPhone

Tags: iphone, gsm

which toolchain / protocol do I need to issue AT/GSM commands to an iPhone via Dock Connector and/or Bluetooth.

Any constructive help is appreciated.

Stefan

Comment: Stefan: I am also looking for the same.If you found anything share the info.